# Paste an image on clipboard to Emacs Org mode file without saving it

Tags: emacs, screenshot, org-mode

As I'm using the Emacs Org mode as a research log, sometime I want to keep track of something via screenshot images, and I definitely don't want to save them. So I'm wondering is there any way to insert those figures into my org mode file, like with word coping them from clipboard?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The exact functionality you want isn't currently implemented, but I would be skeptical of saving lots of images into a research log if your opinion is that you "definitely don't want to save them."

Anyways, the functionality you desire has been expressed in the org-mode mailing list a couple of times in recent years - check

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/33770

http://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg50862.html

The first link includes some code to launch a screenshot utility (via ImageMagick) to [uniquely] save the file and insert an inline link in your org-mode buffer.

As stated in that thread, the code was improved upon and added to org-mode hacks page - which has lots of useful gems:

http://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html

```
(defun my-org-screenshot ()
  "Take a screenshot into a time stamped unique-named file in the
same directory as the org-buffer and insert a link to this file."
  (interactive)
  (setq filename
        (concat
         (make-temp-name
          (concat (buffer-file-name)
                  "_"
                  (format-time-string "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_")) ) ".png"))
  (call-process "import" nil nil nil filename)
  (insert (concat "[[" filename "]]"))
  (org-display-inline-images))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Except I'm still struggling with get 'org-display-inline-images' worked in Aquamacs on Mac. Also I'm wondering since this method is said to be only working on Unix based systems, is there any neat alternative on Windows that you may be aware of?

Comment: @lina This snippet works for me under cygwin with ImageMagick.  ImageMagick has also a windows binary release, but I confess I haven't tried it.  You can substitute `import` in the call to `call-process` for any snapshot utility that can specify the output filename.

Comment: @assem I see the benefit of having images embedded in the document as lina points when your research notes have a lot of churn. If you delete the note containing the file, the image will remain in your file system. Do you think there is any way to modify the script for pasting (raw PNG for instance) and being emacs the one showing the image?

Comment: @ancechu Buffers with lots of image data would have a performance hit on your standard editing features - even if it's just to skip over image data regions.  It would probably be easier to create a hook that asks you if you wish to delete the image file on disk when you delete a note.

Comment: I'm getting an error, " Searching for program: no such file or directory, import" when trying to run the call-proccess 'import'. It works on my work machine but not at home. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a problem: although OP said "screenshot images", the title said pasting from the clipboard. So if one wants to take a screenshot of the whole screen or a big chuck of the screen that doesn't include the emacs window, we would have to hide the emacs window first. So it might be a cleaner solution if it really pastes from clipboard. For instance when using the GUI `gnome-screenshot --interactive`, it hinds the GUI before letting you choose the clip area. Hope I made my point clear.

Answer (score 21):

For OS X users. The following compliments Assem's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17438212/3903368).

The `import` command was not working for me, so I swapped it to `screencapture` with an `-i` argument. I also find it more convenient to use a relative path for the link rather than the absolute.

```
(defun my-org-screenshot ()
  "Take a screenshot into a time stamped unique-named file in the
same directory as the org-buffer and insert a link to this file."
  (interactive)
  (setq filename
        (concat
         (make-temp-name
          (concat (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))
                  "_"
                  (format-time-string "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_")) ) ".png"))
  (call-process "screencapture" nil nil nil "-i" filename)
  (insert (concat "[[./" filename "]]"))
  (org-display-inline-images))
```

## Update: Improvements

I have recently improved on the script a little. It now places screenshots in a subdirectory, creates the directory if required, and only inserts the link into emacs if the image was actually created (i.e., does nothing if you hit ESC). It also works on both Ubuntu and OS X.

```
(defun my-org-screenshot ()
  "Take a screenshot into a time stamped unique-named file in the
same directory as the org-buffer and insert a link to this file."
  (interactive)
  (org-display-inline-images)
  (setq filename
        (concat
         (make-temp-name
          (concat (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))
                  "_imgs/"
                  (format-time-string "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_")) ) ".png"))
  (unless (file-exists-p (file-name-directory filename))
    (make-directory (file-name-directory filename)))
  ; take screenshot
  (if (eq system-type 'darwin)
      (call-process "screencapture" nil nil nil "-i" filename))
  (if (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
      (call-process "import" nil nil nil filename))
  ; insert into file if correctly taken
  (if (file-exists-p filename)
    (insert (concat "[[file:" filename "]]"))))
```

Comment: How do you use this method to take a screenshot of other screens? If I have emacs open when I invoke `my-org-screenshot`, I have to take a screenshot of what is open, i.e., emacs itself. Alternatively, I would have to first remember to move emacs away. And if I'm on another tool I want to take a screenshot of, first I have to bring emacs to focus, move it away and only then invoke `my-org-screenshot`. Feels cumbersome.

Comment: This addressed the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46268816/362298

Answer (score 9):

The answers here focus on initiating the process within emacs. An alternative, on macos, is to place a screenshot image on the system clipboard using cmd-ctl-shift-4, and then to return to Emacs and use emacs lisp to call [pngpaste](https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste) to write the image from clipboard to file, and do whatever you need to with the image file (insert into org, LaTeX, or as a native Emacs inline image etc).

For example, to insert into org:

```
(defun org-insert-clipboard-image (&optional file)
  (interactive "F")
  (shell-command (concat "pngpaste " file))
  (insert (concat "[[" file "]]"))
  (org-display-inline-images))
```

Comment: For linux users, instead of pngpaste you can simply use xclip: ` xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o > file.png ` cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145134/118575

Answer (score 7):

(If of use), I used @assem's code (thank you v.much btw) and created a version that instead creates a sub-folder (if it doesn't exist) like : ${filename}IMG/ 
Then puts an image like  img_date.png  into that folder
and then inserts a relative path into the buffer like:
  `[[ ./${filename}IMG/img_2015...png ]]`

Here is code:

```
(defun my-org-screenshot ()
"Take a screenshot into a time stamped unique-named file in the
sub-directory (%filenameIMG) as the org-buffer and insert a link to this file."
(interactive)

(setq foldername (concat (buffer-file-name) "IMG/"))
(if (not (file-exists-p foldername))
  (mkdir foldername))

(setq imgName (concat "img_" (format-time-string "%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S") ".png"))
(setq imgPath (concat (buffer-file-name) "IMG/" imgName))

(call-process "import" nil nil nil imgPath)

(setq relativeFilename (concat "./"
    (buffer-name) "IMG/" imgName))

(insert (concat "[[" relativeFilename "]]"))
(org-display-inline-images)
)
```

### [Edit 2015.04.09]

In the mean time, I found the above doesn't work well. Technically it works, but it generates a lot of folder names that match the file names, making it tedious to select files as there are folder that have a similar name.

Instead I settled with a solution where I keep all my org files in the same folder, and have an 'img' sub folder' with all my images.

I use code like this to capture images:

```
(defun my/img-maker ()
 "Make folder if not exist, define image name based on time/date" 
  (setq myvar/img-folder-path (concat default-directory "img/"))

  ; Make img folder if it doesn't exist.
  (if (not (file-exists-p myvar/img-folder-path)) ;[ ] refactor thir and screenshot code.
       (mkdir myvar/img-folder-path))

  (setq myvar/img-name (concat "img_" (format-time-string "%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S") ".png"))
  (setq myvar/img-Abs-Path (concat myvar/img-folder-path myvar/img-name)) ;Relative to workspace.

  (setq myvar/relative-filename (concat "./img/" myvar/img-name))
  (insert "[[" myvar/relative-filename "]]" "\n")
)

(defun my/org-screenshot ()
  "Take a screenshot into a time stamped unique-named file in the
 sub-directory (%filenameIMG) as the org-buffer and insert a link to this file."
  (interactive)
  (my/img-maker)
  ;(make-frame-invisible)
  (lower-frame)
  (call-process "import" nil nil nil myvar/img-Abs-Path)

  (raise-frame)
  ;(make-frame-visible)
  (org-display-inline-images)
)
```

and a little bash script in my  org/img folder to archive unreferenced images:

```
#!/bin/sh 

cd ~/git/LeoUfimtsev.github.io/org/img/
mkdir ~/git/LeoUfimtsev.github.io/org/img/archive
FILES=~/git/LeoUfimtsev.github.io/org/img/*.png
for f in $FILES
do
  var_grep_out=$(grep --directories=skip $(basename $f) ../*)
  if [ -z "$var_grep_out" ];
  then 
     echo "Archiving: $f"
     mv $f archive/
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 6):

The [org-download](https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download) package is designed for this.

Comment: for a more substantive writeup using `org-download`, see [this blogpost from Diego Zamboni](https://zzamboni.org/post/how-to-insert-screenshots-in-org-documents-on-macos/) (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810072616/https://zzamboni.org/post/how-to-insert-screenshots-in-org-documents-on-macos/))

Answer (score 6):

I like the images and other material that belongs together with an org file to be located in a clearly associated directory. I am using the org-attachment mechanism for this and wrote a few years back a package [org-attachment-screenshot](https://github.com/dfeich/org-screenshot) that is also available from MELPA. It allows providing a function for defining the directory name (e.g. document name + some postfix) for the attachments, and will also support the standard attachment functionalities, e.g. if you want to define attachments based on entries, and inheriting within entries.
Also provides customizable variable for the snapshot command to be executed.
Please have a look.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows 10 users, I modified the answer provided by @assem to work with out-of-the-box tools:

```
(defun my-org-screenshot ()
  "Take a screenshot into a time stamped unique-named file in the
   same directory as the org-buffer and insert a link to this file."  
   (interactive)
   (setq filename
     (concat
       (make-temp-name
         (concat (buffer-file-name)
              "_"
              (format-time-string "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_")) ) ".png"))
   (shell-command "snippingtool /clip")
   (shell-command (concat "powershell -command \"Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;if ($([System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::ContainsImage())) {$image = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage();[System.Drawing.Bitmap]$image.Save('" filename "',[System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png); Write-Output 'clipboard content saved as file'} else {Write-Output 'clipboard does not contain image data'}\""))
   (insert (concat "[[file:" filename "]]"))
   (org-display-inline-images))
```

The whole write-up can be found [here](http://www.sastibe.de/2018/11/take-screenshots-straight-into-org-files-in-emacs-on-win10/)

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I had to add a `(sleep-for 0.5)` between the invocation snippingtool and the powershell script otherwise the `ContainsImage()` call would return false. But this is great.

Comment: Excellent. A nice addition would be an argument to control if snipping tool is called first.  Sometimes I already have an image on the clipboard and do not want to call the snipping tool.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is for the Windows platform.  Many thanks to **Assem** for giving his solution on which I based mine.

I wrote a C# console app `CbImage2File` that writes the image on the clipboard (if there is one) to a path given as the command line argument.  You will need a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` assembly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CbImage2File
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int FAILURE = 1;

        private static void Failure(string description)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Clipboard does not contain image data");
            Environment.Exit(FAILURE);
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var image = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetImage();

            if (image == null)
            {
                Failure("Clipboard does not contain image data");
            }

            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Failure("You have not specified an output path for the image");
            }

            if (args.Length > 1)
            {
                Failure("You must only specify a file path (1 argument)");
            }

            var filePath = args[0];
            var folderInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath).Directory;

            if (!folderInfo.Exists)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderInfo.FullName);
            }

            image.Save(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

I use Greenshot to take the screenshot, which (via its configuration) automatically copies the screenshot to the clipboard.

I then use a shortcut `C-S-v` to paste the image in the org mode buffer using the function `org-insert-image-from-clipboard`:

```
(defun org-insert-image-from-clipboard ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((the-dir (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))
     (attachments-dir (concat the-dir "attachments"))
     (png-file-name (format-time-string "%a%d%b%Y_%H%M%S.png"))
     (png-path (concat attachments-dir "/" png-file-name))
     (temp-buffer-name "CbImage2File-buffer"))
    (call-process "C:/_code/CbImage2File/CbImage2File/bin/Debug/CbImage2File.exe" nil temp-buffer-name nil png-path)
    (let ((result (with-current-buffer temp-buffer-name (buffer-string))))
      (progn
    (kill-buffer temp-buffer-name)
    (if (string= result "")
        (progn 
          (insert (concat "[[./attachments/" png-file-name "]]"))
          (org-display-inline-images))
      (insert result))))))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-S-v") 'org-insert-image-from-clipboard)
```

This function will work out a file path, then invoke the C# app to create `png` file, then it will add the image tag and then call `org-display-inline-images` to show the image.  If there is no image on the clipboard, it will paste in the response from the C# app.