# How to get nondirectory part of absolute file name?

Tags: emacs, filenames

I would like to ask how to get the file name from interactive command in lisp.

Btw, this is taken from another stackoverflow thread.

[Paste an image on clipboard to Emacs Org mode file without saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435995/paste-an-image-on-clipboard-to-emacs-org-mode-file-without-saving-it)

```
(defun markdown-insert-clipboard-image (&optional file)
  (interactive "G")
  (shell-command (concat "pngpaste " file))
  (insert (concat "![" file "](" file ")")))
```

My problem is the file is using absolute path instead of just the filename causing the file to have an error when pushed to the server.

Instead of yahoocom.png only,
I get

`/Users/test/test/test/test/yahoocom.png`

I would only want to get

`yahoocom.png`

Is there anyway that I can modify the code so that it only uses the filename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`file-name-nondirectory`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html):

> Return file name FILENAME sans its directory.
>   For example, in a Unix-syntax file name,
>   this is everything after the last slash,
>   or the entire name if it contains no slash.

Note that you probably do ***not*** want to pass the base name to `shell-command` (use either the original absolute path or [`file-relative-name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Relative-File-Names.html))

PS. I suggest that you replace `"G"` with `"fImage file name: "` in your [`interactive`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html) form because your function will fail if the `file` does not exist.

Comment: This perfectly solved it. Thank You. I already replaced with "F" which was the one in the original stack exchange post. I just tried the different paramters. Thank You,

Answer (score 5):

While sds's answer indeed gives what you directly asked for, I think what you're really looking for might be to have the relative name of the file (which will be just the same if the file is in the current working directory).  If so, try `file-relative-name`:

> Convert FILENAME to be relative to DIRECTORY (default: `default-directory`).
>   This function returns a relative file name that is equivalent to FILENAME
>   when used with that default directory as the default.
>   If FILENAME is a relative file name, it will be interpreted as existing in
>   `default-directory`.
>   If FILENAME and DIRECTORY lie on different machines or on different drives
>   on a DOS/Windows machine, it returns FILENAME in expanded form.